# Python: Applying function to list of tems

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

I have following code snippet that helps me to get Google Trends data (see https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends):

```
trend_payload = {'q': 'Dogs, Cats, Catfood, Dogfood','date': '01/2015 12m'}
trend = pytrend.trend(trend_payload)
df = pytrend.trend(trend_payload, return_type='dataframe')
df
```

As this query has the disadvantage that Google Trends normalizes all data based on the queried data, I prefer to make each a single call and chain the df next to each other. I thought about a function like this:

```
queries = ['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Catfood','Dogfood']

function(queries)
    trend_payload = {'q': queries, 'date': '01/2015 12m'}
    trend = pytrend.trend(trend_payload)
    df = pytrend.trend(trend_payload, return_type='dataframe')

# then put every df of each query next to each other
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: do you want to work with [function([query,]) for query in queries] ? (Where function returns the df).

Comment: Yes, I want a function that is applied to each item in the list "queries". The results should be put into a dataframe that contains the results for each item in the list.

Comment: Are the dataframes panda's dataframes? In this case you can take advantage of the `concat` function to concatenate the df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply concatenate DFs as [jimifiki has already proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102772/python-applying-function-to-list-of-tems#comment67478072_40102772):

```
df = pd.concat([pytrend.trend({'q': x, 'date': '01/2015 12m'},
                              return_type='dataframe')
                for x in queries], axis=1)
```

or in function:

```
def get_trends(queries, dt):
    return pd.concat([pytrend.trend({'q': x, 'date': dt},
                                    return_type='dataframe')
                      for x in queries], axis=1)

df = get_trends(queries, '01/2015 12m')
```

Demo:

```
In [24]: df = get_trends(queries, '01/2015 12m')

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
            cats   dogs  catfood  dogfood
Date
2015-01-04  74.0   85.0     65.0     47.0
2015-01-11  74.0   84.0     60.0     52.0
2015-01-18  72.0   82.0     49.0     57.0
2015-01-25  69.0   78.0     45.0     37.0
2015-02-01  73.0   77.0     51.0     52.0
...          ...    ...      ...      ...
2015-11-29  83.0   80.0     47.0     49.0
2015-12-06  80.0   79.0     70.0     50.0
2015-12-13  83.0   84.0     67.0     49.0
2015-12-20  89.0   91.0     61.0     58.0
2015-12-27  90.0  100.0     58.0     45.0

[52 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: one last question here:

Comment: I need to anchor the query to another term. i.e. every query has one variable that is static and another that is from the list. So the query is always pytrend.trend({'q': 'animals, x', 'date': '01/2015 12m'}, return_type='dataframe') for x in queries], axis=1). Can we also do this?

Comment: @RPacker, so `animals` - is a constant?

Comment: Yes. In order to avoid a too long question, I opened it up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108906/python-function-variable-and-string

Comment: @RPacker, i've answered you there

Answer (score 1):

You can work on this:

```
queries = ['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Catfood','Dogfood']

def function(queries):
    trend_payload = {'q': queries, 'date': '01/2015 12m'}
    trend = pytrend.trend(trend_payload)
    df = pytrend.trend(trend_payload, return_type='dataframe')
    return df 

list_of_df = [function([query,]) for query in queries]
```

then you have to `concat` the data frames in the list.

More elegantly you can call:

```
list_of_df = map(function, queries)
```

in this case you should rewrite `function` so that it accepts a single item.
If you don't want to modify `function` you can write this:

```
list_of_df = map(lambda x: function([x,]), queries)
```

Comment: When applying the very last step, it says: "list_of_df = map(lambda x: function([x,], queries)
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"

Comment: Okay, there was a bracket missing. But now: "list_of_df = map(lambda x: function([x,], queries)) --> TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments."

Comment: map applies the function (first argument) to each element of (second argument) and put them in a list. Since your function takes a list as argument you need to adapt the function you pass as first argument: `lambda x: (function[x,])` is a function that takes x, put it in a single element list and passes it to function.

Comment: I'm sorry but when I call list_of_df, the list is empty? "<map at 0x10595a630>" Good news is that there is no exception anymore.

Comment: Is function returning the df? It should.

Comment: When I type function(queries), it only responds a df with the first value in the list.

Comment: I solved it with the function below. Anyways, thanks a lot! I will upvote.