# Python function: variable and string

Tags: python, string, list, function

I have following formula to check (Thanks for helping me on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102772/python-applying-function-to-list-of-tems/40102936?noredirect=1#comment67478880_40102936)!).

```
queries = ['dog','cat','hamster']

    def get_trends(queries):
        return pd.concat([pytrend.trend({'q': x, 'date': '01/2015 12m'}, return_type='dataframe')
    for x in queries], axis=1)

get_trends(queries)
```

This function fires a Google Trends query for each item in the list and puts the returning dataframes next to each other. What I need to do now is to do exactly the same, but have each one static variable (pet) in the query.

For example, a query without the formula would be

```
return pytrend.trend({'q': 'pet, dog', 'date': '01/2015 12m'}, return_type='dataframe')
```

I know I could try

```
queries = ['pet, dog','pet, cat','pet, hamster']
```

But maybe there's a more elegant way?

I tried

```
static =['pet']
return pytrend.trend({'q': ''' + static + x + ''', 'date': '01/2015 12m'}, return_type='dataframe')
```

but wasn't successful with that.

Comment: Maybe you can use `format`? What is `x` in the first block of code?

Comment: See above, I updated the code.

Comment: Oh okay. You could do: `return pd.concat([pytrend.trend({'q': static+x, 'date': '01/2015 12m'}, return_type='dataframe')
    for x in queries], axis=1)`

Comment: Where `static = 'pet '`

Comment: Does that work for you?

Comment: No: "can only concatenate list (not "str") to list". Somehow, it must be like ''q: 'pet, dog'. Note that is must be in ' ' and separated by a comma.

Comment: By the way I think you were getting the error `"can only concatenate list (not "str") to list"` because you made `static = ['pet']`, which is a list. Instead of `static = 'pet '` which is a string like I said :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
In [54]: %paste
static = 'animals'
animals = ['dog','cat','hamster']
queries = ['{}, {}'.format(static, x) for x in animals]
## -- End pasted text --

In [55]: queries
Out[55]: ['animals, dog', 'animals, cat', 'animals, hamster']
```

now you can pass `queries` to your function:

```
get_trends(queries)
```

Comment: It was my understanding that OP didn't want to add `'pet'` to the start of every element. Not sure if that's what OP meant but if not, this is the solution.

Comment: That works just fine. Only one last issue: How can I prevent that the columns are each alphabetically ordered when concatenating the dataframe. Because: cat dog dog hamster dog is what the df looks like.